# underscore: what's meaning of 'context' in the source code comment

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm confused about the code below; What's the 'context' in comment meaning for?
Is it used for scope ?

```
    // If the value of the named `property` is a function then invoke it with the
    // `object` as context; otherwise, return it.
    _.result = function(object, property) {
      if (object == null) return void 0;
      var value = object[property];
      return _.isFunction(value) ? object[property]() : value;
    };
```

[example in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/belere/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "context" of a function call is the value given to `this`. In the code you posted, the function is invoked like this:

```
object[property]()
```

The property value is fetched from `object`, and so the rules for function invocation say that `object` should be the value for `this`. If the code you posted had looked like this instead:

```
return _.isFunction(value) ? value() : value;
```

then the function call would have been made differently: the value of `this` would be the global object (`window` in a browser), or `undefined` if running in "strict" mode.

Comment: 3q, and I thought I didn't really understand  `var value = object[property];` do what